# Aurelia/Karma/Istanbul Cannot read property 'skip' and 'decl' of undefined but generates a rapport

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner, aurelia, istanbul

Last week I wrote a lot of tests with Mocha, Sinon and Karma for my Aurelia application. Now is the moment to setup Istanbul for the code coverage.
When karma completed his task will Istanbul generate the coverage and throws an error in the console and in one file of HTML rapport.

```
25 10 2019 09:41:56.600:ERROR [coverage]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined
    at C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul\lib\object-utils.js:110:43
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at computeSimpleTotals (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul\lib\object-utils.js:108:28)
    at Object.summarizeFileCoverage (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul\lib\object-utils.js:215:25)
    at C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:558:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HtmlReport.writeReport (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:557:27)
    at writeReport (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\karma-coverage\lib\reporter.js:68:16)
    at C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\karma-coverage\lib\reporter.js:297:11
    at fs.stat (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\karma\lib\helper.js:148:7)
    at callback (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
Karma has exited with 0
```

The HTML page

```
Cannot read property 'decl' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'decl' of undefined
    at Object.keys.forEach.fName (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-reports\lib\html\annotator.js:92:31)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at annotateFunctions (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-reports\lib\html\annotator.js:88:26)
    at Object.annotateSourceCode (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-reports\lib\html\annotator.js:238:9)
    at HtmlReport.onDetail (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-reports\lib\html\index.js:265:27)
    at Visitor.(anonymous function) [as onDetail] (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:34:30)
    at ReportNode.Node.visit (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:114:17)
    at getChildren.forEach.child (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:118:15)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at ReportNode.Node.visit (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:117:24)
    at getChildren.forEach.child (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:118:15)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at ReportNode.Node.visit (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:117:24)
    at Tree.visit (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-lib-report\lib\tree.js:150:20)
    at Object.keys.forEach.name (C:\Projecten\*HIDDEN*\dev\*HIDDEN*\node_modules\istanbul-api\lib\reporter.js:94:18)
    at Array.forEach ()
```

This is my Karma config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: path.dirname(__dirname),

        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon', 'karma-typescript'],

        'plugins': [
            require('karma-mocha'),
            require('karma-sinon'),
            require('karma-chai'),
            require('karma-webpack'),
            require('karma-mocha-reporter'), 
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-typescript'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
            require('karma-istanbul-threshold')
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'test/karma-bundle.js': ['webpack'],
            'ClientApp/**/*.ts': ['webpack', 'coverage']
        },
        webpack: require('../webpack.unit.config')({ env: 'production', prod: false }),

        reporters: ['junit', 'mocha', 'progress', 'coverage', 'coverage-istanbul'],

        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['html'],
            dir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'coverage-karma'),
            includeAllSources: false,
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: false,
            combineBrowserReports: false
        },

        webpackServer: { noInfo: true }, 
    });
}
```

I removed the unnecessary code from the config file.

I added the following rule to my Webpack config:

```
...
{
    test: /\.(ts)/,
    options: {
        esModules: true,
        produceSourceMap: true,
        debug: true
    },
    include: path.resolve(srcDir),
    loader:'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
},
....
```

Comment: After a long trial and error, I resolved one of those two errors. The 'decl' is thrown from the Aurelia framework with the '@inject' function. When I removed this line the error was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the errors are resolved.
The first error about the 'decl' is from a @inject in my code. By removing the @inject the problem was resolved.

After reinstalling my node.js the 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined' error was gone.